# android/java unexpected top level exception bad class file magic version 0034.0000 -> VerifyError

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, verifyerror

I'm having a big problem with android/intellij/gradle that I'm hoping someone can help me with. I have an external library that I wrote and I have it imported into an android project. The external library was first compiled with java 1.8 and I got a `unexpected top level exception bad class file magic version 0034.0000` error. After reading through various Stackoverflow questions (like [this][1]), and getting no where with the problem, I realized that the external library had to be compiled using JDK 1.7 which I then did. 

Now this initial error, I believe, was based on an exception that I wrote that one of my classes throws. For some reason the unexpected top level exception was pointing to a an error parsing my exception class (which extends Exception). This isn't anything big, its simply,

```
public class MyException extends Exception {public MyException(String msg){super(msg);}
```

After compiling with 1.7, I no longer receive the error. How ever I am now getting a verify error and it seems to only be getting called when I instantiate a class that throws an exception. I have a simple java bean in the external library with getters and setters, and an enum and both work in the android app without issue.

I also tried to store the jar file in the libs directory to see if that would solve the problem, but I get nothing.

Is there some sort of issue with android and custom exceptions?

Edit: I tried copying the class files into the android project and the original issue goes away. The only new thing that arises is that I get a an error from Jackson `Didn't find class "org.joda.convert.ToString" on path`. I could probably fix this and use a different JSON library, but I would like to avoid using the class files in this project directly and would prefer to use it as an external jar

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public class MyException extends Exception`?

Comment: @Gosu Correct. I have it the right way in the library I just wrote it here quick. Also, running tests on the library results in no issues.